# UseEffect with no dependency infinite loops in FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect, use-state

I have the following code below:

```
    <FlatList
        ListHeaderComponent={() => <DeliverySection selectedAddress={selectedAddress} setSelectedAddress={setSelectedAddress}/>}
        data={items}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => <CheckoutGroup shop={item} />}
    />
```

`<DeliverySection />` does an API call - however I get an error saying `too many attempts` which is why I found out that `<DeliverySection />` is going through an infinite loop

`selectedAddress` and `setSelectedAddress` are `useState` hooks from the parent component, so that `<DeliverySection />` can update them.

If it helps, this is my `<DeliverySection />` source code:

```
const [addresses, setAddresses] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    AddressCalls.getUserAddresses(USER.token)
    .then(r => {
        console.log("received response");
        setAddresses(r.data);
        let addresses = r.data;
        let preferredAddress = addresses.filter(obj => obj.preferred == true);
        setSelectedAddress(preferredAddress.length == 0 ? addresses[0] : preferredAddress[0]);
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e.response.data.message));
}, []);
```

Basically it calls in the saved user addresses, and use that as a selection to set the selected address to `setSelectedAddress`. I'm confused, because it's looping even if there are no dependencies in the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: What is the code for getUserAddresses?

Comment: My guess is the loop is either coming from whatever getUserAddresses does, or in your parent component when selectedAddress is set in DeliverySection component. Should provide sources on both.

Comment: @Andrew `getUserAddresses` is just an axios `GET` call.

Comment: ```return axios.get(`${API_URL}/v1/billing-info`)```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?